# PDFClown cannot edit created PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfclown

I’m using PDF Clown (in C#) to generate a PDF file containing graphics (lines, polygons and circles) on separate layers.
Now I run into a problem and I have searched the internet for days but cannot find the solution.

I have the following problem:
How can I make sure that the PDF generated by PDFClown can be edited/modified using another application like for instance Blue Beam or Adobe Acrobat?
At this moment the generated PDF looks ok but I’m unable to select and modify any of the graphics (lines, polygons etc.) on any layer.

Should I set something during creating layers or graphic objects?

A link to the generated file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1om4UByGhfS1D9OOCYzhHrNjNQeNcJI-0

I would really appreciate your help!
Following is piece of the code where a polyline is created.

```
var pdfFile = new File();

m_PdfDocument = pdfFile.Document;
m_PdfDocument.PageSize = PageFormat.GetSize(PageFormat.SizeEnum.A4);
m_PdfDocument.Version = Version.Get("1.6");


m_PdfPage = new Page(m_PdfDocument);
m_PdfDocument.Pages.Add(m_PdfPage);

var primitiveComposer = new PrimitiveComposer(m_PdfPage);

primitiveComposer.SetLineJoin(LineJoinEnum.Miter);
primitiveComposer.SetLineCap(LineCapEnum.Square);
primitiveComposer.SetLineWidth(2);

primitiveComposer.SetStrokeColor(DeviceRGBColor.Get(System.Drawing.Color.Black))
// Flip Y axis!
primitiveComposer.SetMatrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, m_PdfPage.Size.Height);

primitiveComposer.BeginLayer(layer);
primitiveComposer.DrawPolyline(line.ToArray());
primitiveComposer.Stroke();
primitiveComposer.End();

primitiveComposer.Flush();

pdfFile.Save(filename, SerializationModeEnum.Standard);
```

Edit2: New test file
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PHACkr2EcWrdIP5XocCnwDtakQ-P0hJY

Edit 18-01-2019
In Bluebeam Revu a polyline entry looks like this:

```
%PDF-1.5
%Çì¢
1 0 obj<</CreationDate(D:20190111132455+01'00')/ModDate(D:20190111132818+01'00')/Aut
hor(e.debont)/Creator(Bluebeam Revu x64)/Producer(Bluebeam PDF Library 18)>>
endobj
2 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 3 0 R/OCProperties 7 0 R>>
endobj
3 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Kids[4 0 R]/Count 1>>
endobj
4 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Kids[5 0 R]/Count 1/Parent 3 0 R>>
endobj
5 0 obj<</Type/Page/Parent 4 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 594.72 841.68]/Annots 19 0 R>>
endobj
6 0 obj<</Order[8 0 R]>>
endobj
7 0 obj<</OCGs[8 0 R]/D 6 0 R>>
endobj
8 0 obj<</Type/OCG/Name(Test)>>
endobj
19 0 obj[21 0 R]
endobj
21 0 obj<</Subj(Polylijn)/Type/Annot/P 5 0 R/F 4/C[1 0 0]/CreationDate
(D:20190111132642+01'00')/T(e.debont)/Subtype/PolyLine/AP<</N
22 0 R>>/IC[1 0 0]/M(D:20190111132642+01'00')/Vertices[225.8323 629.0071 
273.3759 657.8729 354.8793 583.5859]/Rect[220.3323 578.0859 360.3793 
663.3729]/NM(MQJCWGUIXHEAEWJU)/OC 8 0 R>>
endobj
22 0 obj<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Form/FormType 1/BBox[220.3323 578.0859 
360.3793 663.3729]/Resources<</ProcSet[/PDF]>>/Matrix[1 0 0 1 -220.3323 
-578.0859]/Length 84>>
stream
1 0 0 RG 1 0 0 rg 1 w 225.8323 629.0071 m 273.3759 657.8729 l 354.8793 
583.5859 l S 
endstream
endobj
xref
0 23
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000183 00000 n 
0000000246 00000 n 
0000000296 00000 n 
0000000359 00000 n 
0000000443 00000 n 
0000000475 00000 n 
0000000514 00000 n 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000553 00000 n 
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000577 00000 n 
0000000900 00000 n 
trailer<</Size 23/Info 1 0 R/ID[<2753c66a6950982e644007ca4324fe83> 
<2753c66a6950982e644007ca4324fe83>]/Root 2 0 R>>
startxref
1175
%%EOF
```

PDFClown generates this (between stream and endstream there is binary data):

```
9 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 60 >>
stream
Binary data
endstream
endobj
10 0 obj
<</Type /OCMD /P /AllOn /OCGs [8 0 R ] >>
endobj
11 0 obj
<</Type /XObject /Subtype /Form /BBox [0 0 594.71997 841.67999 ] /Resources 
<</Properties <</1 10 0 R >> >> /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 60 >>
stream
Binary data
endstream
endobj
```

How can I using PDFClown write the Bluebeam output?
Or at least how do I prevent using /Filter /FlateDecode?

Comment: @mjwills, Sorry, I have added an excerpt of the code used.

Comment: Can you add a link to one such PDF?

Comment: @usr2564301, I have added a link (I hope)

Comment: Okay, I got it and tested. This is not a problem with PDFClown nor with your code, it is a [general computing hardware and/or software problem](https://superuser.com/) instead. I *can* edit the PDF **with suitable software**, such as Acrobat Pro and Adobe Illustrator. My guess is you are simply using the wrong software to edit.

Comment: @usr2564301, First of all thanks for testing.
I have a pdf file generated with Blue Beam which I can edit with Adbode Reader.
I can use the select tool to select a line or polyline and move it for example.
I cannot do that on the file generated by PDFClown.
Also when the guy using Blue Beam tries to edit PDFClown file he cannot edit it!

Comment: Just like @usr2564301 says, the PDF looks ok. The only thing that might be irritating some software is that in the page content stream there is a **q** / **Q** (save and restore graphics state) nesting depth of more than 28. In times before PDF became an ISO standard a maximum depth of graphics state nesting of 28 was documented as implementation limit in the Adobe PDF References. You perhaps should not nest that deeply. Other than that that non-editability is an arbitrary limitation of the editing software you tested.

Comment: @mkl
This nesting depth I was not aware of.
How can I see what the nesting depth is?
I have made some changes in the code, not using BeginLocalState anymore.
Does this make any difference?
I have put a link to a new test file in the post.

Comment: Your new file does not have that **q** / **Q** nesting depth anymore. (As an aside, in general it's not a bad idea to use save and restore state instruction, one should merely not nest too deeply.) If the editors you test cannot edit the new file, this is an arbitrary limitation in them.

Comment: @mkl
Thanks for your help!
I will have a talk with the end user.

Comment: If you eventually have to create PDFs a specific editor can edit, you'll have to take files that editor can edit and files you create, compare their very internals to determine the differences, and then try to create PDFs in a similar manner. If you have not yet dealt with PDF content streams, that will be quite a feat.

Comment: Is that XObject created by Bluebeam an appearance stream of a **PolyLine** annotation? In that case you should change your code not to draw paths in the page content stream but instead add a `Polyline` annotation.

Comment: @mkl,
I have updated the Bluebeam example to include the complete file.
I'm not sure I know what you mean.
Could you please ellaborate?
A C# example creating the PDF content as seen in Bluebeam would be more than welcome!
Thanks in advance for trying to help me out, much appreciated!!

Comment: The complete file shows that Bluebeam handles **PolyLine** annotations. I'll try and find some time later to post something on that but I cannot promise a time.

Comment: @mkl,
That would be great!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example PDF contents posted indicate that the kind of line graphics your target PDF editing software can edit are not the paths in the page *content* but instead **PolyLine** *annotations*.

You can create a simple **PolyLine** annotation with PDF Clown like this:

```
org.pdfclown.files.File file = new org.pdfclown.files.File();
Document document = file.Document;
Page page = new Page(document);
document.Pages.Add(page);

new Polyline(page, page.Box, "Test-PolyLine")
{
    Color = new DeviceRGBColor(1, 0, 0),
    Vertices = new List<PointF>() { new PointF(50, 50), new PointF(50, 250), new PointF(150, 150), new PointF(250, 250), new PointF(250, 50) }
};

file.Save("PolyLine-PdfClown.pdf", SerializationModeEnum.Standard);
```

The result in Adobe Reader:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: you are a life saver!!
Got it working now.
Thank you very much indeed!